# Stata Renaming Variables using first line data

Tags: foreach, rename, stata

I used `insheet` to read in CSV format data. The names of the variables should be the first line of the dataset. I have a lot of variables and many years of data to read in so I would like to do this using a `foreach var` loop as follows:

```
   input str8 x str8 y str8 z
   first second third
   3 6 2
   4 1 2
   8 7 6
   end

   foreach var of varlist * {
     rename variable "`var'" "`=`var'[1]'"
   }
```

Unfortunately, I receive a `syntax error` response.

I'm assuming the problem must be in the way I specified the new name. I was extrapolating from this Q&A: http://www.stata.com/statalist/archive/2011-09/msg01109.html

Comment: `insheet` has a `[no]names` option. The `help` states: "**[no]names** informs Stata whether variable names are included on the first line of the file."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not to do with `foreach`. Your `input` code didn't run for me but that seems a side-issue.

The main problems seem to be

1. `rename` does not include the syntax `variable` unless that is a variable name.
2. `rename` does not use double quotes.

See the help for `rename`.

This works and keeps on going.

```
clear 
input str8 x str8 y str8 z
"first" "second" "third"
"3" "6" "2"
"4" "1" "2"
"8" "7" "6"
end

foreach var of varlist * {
   rename `var' `=`var'[1]'
}
drop in 1 
destring, replace 
l 

     +------------------------+
     | first   second   third |
     |------------------------|
  1. |     3        6       2 |
  2. |     4        1       2 |
  3. |     8        7       6 |
     +------------------------+
```

However, `insheet` is an out-of-date command.

See `help import` or http://www.stata.com/manuals14/dimport.pdf to see that `import delimited` is what to use and that it supports variable names on the first line of the data file, so none of this should be needed, unless you have access only to an older version of Stata.

(If you are using an old version, it is always a good idea to be explicit about that in any forum supporting Stata questions.)

EDIT: As @Roberto Ferrer points out `insheet` also supports variable names on the first line.